# How do I use the subject line from emails to sort attachments into local folders?

Tags: vba, outlook

I receive automated emails that have attachments. Different customers are identified by the subject line.
I drag and drop the attachments into a new email and send it to the appropriate customer.

I want to automate this process so that I can click and automatically generate the emails for each customer with the appropriate attachments included.

I scraped together some things I found on the internet. It works for one customer.
It loops through a sub-folder (Test2) and copies each attachment to a local file on my machine (test2), then it generates an email and attaches all the items from the local folder to the new email and sends the email to X.

```vb
Send()
    SaveEmailAttachmentsToFolder "Test Folder2", "pdf", "C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\test2"
End Sub
    
Sub SaveEmailAttachmentsToFolder(OutlookFolderInInbox As String, _
                                 ExtString As String, destFolder As String)
    Dim ns As NameSpace
    Dim Inbox As MAPIFolder
    Dim SubFolder As MAPIFolder
    Dim item As Object
    Dim Atmt As Attachment
    
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim MyDocPath As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim wsh As Object
    Dim fs As Object

    On Error GoTo ThisMacro_err

    Set ns = GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set SubFolder = Inbox.Folders(OutlookFolderInInbox)

    i = 0
    ' Check subfolder for messages and exit of none found
    If SubFolder.Items.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "There are no messages in this folder : " & OutlookFolderInInbox, _
            vbInformation, "Nothing Found"
        Set SubFolder = Nothing
        Set Inbox = Nothing
        Set ns = Nothing
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Create DestFolder if DestFolder = ""
    If destFolder = "" Then
        Set wsh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        MyDocPath = wsh.SpecialFolders.item("mydocuments")
        destFolder = MyDocPath & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yyyy hh-mm-ss")
        If Not fs.FolderExists(destFolder) Then
            fs.CreateFolder destFolder
        End If
    End If

    If Right(destFolder, 1) <> "\" Then
        destFolder = destFolder & "\"
    End If

    ' Check each message for attachments and extensions
    For Each item In SubFolder.Items
        For Each Atmt In item.Attachments
            If LCase(Right(Atmt.FileName, Len(ExtString))) = LCase(ExtString) Then
                FileName = destFolder & item.SenderName & " " & Atmt.FileName
                Atmt.SaveAsFile FileName
                i = i + 1
            End If
        Next Atmt
    Next item

    ' Show this message when Finished
    If i > 0 Then
        MsgBox "You can find the files here : " _
             & destFolder, vbInformation, "Finished!"
    Else
        MsgBox "No attached files in your mail.", vbInformation, "Finished!"
    End If

    ''This portion generates the email
    '' pulls the attachments from local test 2 folder
    '' sends email to specified email address

    Dim mess_body As String, StrFile As String, StrPath As String
    Dim appOutLook As Outlook.Application
    Dim MailOutLook As Outlook.MailItem

    Set appOutLook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set MailOutLook = appOutLook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    '~~> Change path here
    StrPath = "C:\Users\KTucker\Desktop\test2\"
    
    With MailOutLook
        .BodyFormat = olFormatRichText
        .To = "Email@email.com"
        .Subject = "This an email subject"
        .HTMLBody = "This is an email body"


        '~~> *.* for all files
        StrFile = Dir(StrPath + "*.*")

        Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
            .Attachments.Add StrPath & StrFile
            StrFile = Dir
        Loop

        '.DeleteAfterSubmit = True
        .Send
    End With

    MsgBox "Reports have been sent", vbOKOnly
    
    'Clear memory
ThisMacro_exit:
    Set SubFolder = Nothing
    Set Inbox = Nothing
    Set ns = Nothing
    Set fs = Nothing
    Set wsh = Nothing
    Exit Sub
    
    ' Error information
ThisMacro_err:
    MsgBox "An unexpected error has occurred." _
         & vbCrLf & "Please note and report the following information." _
         & vbCrLf & "Macro Name: SaveEmailAttachmentsToFolder" _
         & vbCrLf & "Error Number: " & Err.Number _
         & vbCrLf & "Error Description: " & Err.Description _
         , vbCritical, "Error!"
    Resume ThisMacro_exit

End Sub
```

The top half copies all of the attachments from the 'Test Folder2' sub-folder, then saves it to 'Desktop/Test2' folder.
The second half generates a new email, pulls all the documents in the local Test2 file and attaches it to the new email, then sends it to the specific address.

What code could I add in the top half that would parse the same sub-folder (Test Folder2) and save all attachments from emails with one subject line to one local folder, and all attachments from emails with a different subject line to another folder?

Answer (score 0):

```
 Set appOutLook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
```

First of all, there is no need to create a new Outlook Application instance in the code if you run the macro in Outlook. The `Application` property is available out of the box.

> What code could I add in the top half that would parse the same sub-folder (Test Folder2) and save all attachments from emails with one subject line to one local folder, and all attachments from emails with a different subject line to another folder?

It seems you just need to create a subfolder on the disk according to the `Subject` property and save item's attachments there. For example, a raw sketch:

```
 'Create DestFolder if DestFolder = ""
    If destFolder = "" Then
        Set wsh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        MyDocPath = wsh.SpecialFolders.item("mydocuments")
        destFolder = MyDocPath & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yyyy hh-mm-ss")
        If Not fs.FolderExists(destFolder) Then
            fs.CreateFolder destFolder
        End If
    End If

    If Right(destFolder, 1) <> "\" Then
        destFolder = destFolder & "\"
    End If

    ' Check each message for attachments and extensions
    Dim itemDestFolder as String
    For Each item In SubFolder.Items
        If item.Attachments.Count > 0 then 

           Set itemDestFolder = destFolder & "\" & item.Subject
           If Not fs.FolderExists(itemDestFolder) Then
              fs.CreateFolder itemDestFolder
           End If

           For Each Atmt In item.Attachments
             If LCase(Right(Atmt.FileName, Len(ExtString))) = LCase(ExtString) Then
                FileName = itemDestFolder & item.SenderName & " " & Atmt.FileName
                Atmt.SaveAsFile FileName
                i = i + 1
             End If
           Next Atmt
        End If
    Next item
```

Comment: I keep getting an 'Object Required' error. I have tried a couple changes but cannot seem to shake that error.                                                                                                                           I am not sure what you are trying to do with the                                                       
 Set itemDestFolder = destFolder & "\" & item.Subject   I assume that itemDestFolder is where we want to save the attachments, but I need to hard code the subject string somewhere right?

Comment: It looks like you need to use ``` Set itemDestFolder = destFolder & "\" & item.Subject  & "\" ``` . The file path should end up with ```\```.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It is still giving me an object error. Can you explain to me how the DestFolder element is working? That seems to be throwing off the whole Sub, do we need to call it from the 'SaveEmailAttachmentsToFolder element?

Comment: @Tucker `Set` is for objects. In this case `itemDestFolder ` is a string so remove the word`Set`.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev If there is no email that for one of the folders, it sends a blank email is there anyway I can check before sending an email if there are attachments or not? Then not send if there aren't any? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To create subfolders based on Item.Subject.

```vb
Sub SaveEmailAttachmentsToFolder(OutlookFolderInInbox As String, _
                                 ExtString As String, destFolderPath As String)

    Dim ns As NameSpace
    Dim Inbox As Folder
    Dim SubFolder As Folder

    Dim item As Object
    Dim Atmt As Attachment
    Dim FileName As String

    Dim i As Long

    Dim wsh As Object
    Dim fs As Object

    Dim itmSubjFldrName As String   ' Subfolder of destFolderPath
    Dim attFolderPath As String '

    Set ns = GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set SubFolder = Inbox.Folders(OutlookFolderInInbox)

    i = 0

    ' Check subfolder for messages and exit if none found
    If SubFolder.Items.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "There are no messages in this folder : " & OutlookFolderInInbox, _
               vbInformation, "Nothing Found"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Right(destFolderPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        destFolderPath = destFolderPath & "\"
    End If

    Set wsh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    ' Check each message for attachments and extensions
    For Each item In SubFolder.Items

        If item.Attachments.Count > 0 Then

            ' Simple example for
            '  determining a folder name based on subject.
            ' You must also remove characters not valid in a folder name
            '  for example the : in RE: and FW:
            itmSubjFldrName = Left(item.Subject, 20)

            attFolderPath = destFolderPath & itmSubjFldrName & "\"

            If Not fs.FolderExists(attFolderPath) Then
                fs.CreateFolder attFolderPath
            End If

            For Each Atmt In item.Attachments

                If LCase(Right(Atmt.FileName, Len(ExtString))) = LCase(ExtString) Then

                    FileName = attFolderPath & item.SenderName & " " & Atmt.FileName
                    Atmt.SaveAsFile FileName

                    i = i + 1

                End If

            Next Atmt
        End If

    Next item

    ' Show this message when Finished
    If i > 0 Then
        MsgBox "You can find the files here : " _
             & destFolderPath, vbInformation, "Finished!"
    Else
        MsgBox "No attached files in your mail.", vbInformation, "Finished!"
    End If

End Sub
```